# How do I fill an R Matrix with values which are calculated from row and column names?

Tags: r, matrix

I have an empty 7 by 7 matrix but I want it to look like this

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
2   NA  0   1   2   3   4   5
3   NA  NA  0   1   2   3   4
4   NA  NA  NA  0   1   2   3
5   NA  NA  NA  NA  0   1   2
6   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0   1
7   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0
```

I would like to know how I can populate it so that I get the value when column name > row name, subtract row name from column name else leave it as NA

I would also like to know how this is done if it's not a square matrix, and the row and column names are dates i.e.

```
    26/03/2012  02/04/2012  09/04/2012  16/04/2012  23/04/2012  30/04/2012  07/05/2012  14/05/2012  21/05/2012  28/05/2012
26/03/2012  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
02/04/2012  NA  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
09/04/2012  NA  NA  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
16/04/2012  NA  NA  NA  0   1   2   3   4   5   6
23/04/2012  NA  NA  NA  NA  0   1   2   3   4   5
30/04/2012  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0   1   2   3   4
07/05/2012  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0   1   2   3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you could use `outer`:

```
mat <- t(outer(1:7,1:7,"-"))
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- NA

mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]   NA    0    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]   NA   NA    0    1    2    3    4
[4,]   NA   NA   NA    0    1    2    3
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    1    2
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    1
[7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0
```

This works with other kinds of data, for example dates:

```
library(lubridate)

dates <- ymd("2014-01-01") + dweeks(1:7)


mat <- t(outer(dates,dates,"-"))
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- NA

mat
Time differences in secs
     [,1]   [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]
[1,]    0 604800 1209600 1814400 2419200 3024000 3628800
[2,]   NA      0  604800 1209600 1814400 2419200 3024000
[3,]   NA     NA       0  604800 1209600 1814400 2419200
[4,]   NA     NA      NA       0  604800 1209600 1814400
[5,]   NA     NA      NA      NA       0  604800 1209600
[6,]   NA     NA      NA      NA      NA       0  604800
[7,]   NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       0
```

However, in general it is better to keep data in data.frames, rather than doing math with the row and column names of a matrix! for example:

```
one <- dmy(c("26/03/2012","02/04/2012","09/04/2012"))
two <- dmy(c("26/03/2012","02/04/2012"))

df <- expand.grid(one,two)


transform(df,diffdate = Var1 - Var2)

        Var1       Var2     diffdate
1 2012-03-26 2012-03-26       0 secs
2 2012-04-02 2012-03-26  604800 secs
3 2012-04-09 2012-03-26 1209600 secs
4 2012-03-26 2012-04-02 -604800 secs
5 2012-04-02 2012-04-02       0 secs
6 2012-04-09 2012-04-02  604800 secs

transform(df,diffdate = seconds_to_period(Var1 - Var2))

            Var1       Var2     diffdate
1 2012-03-26 2012-03-26           0S
2 2012-04-02 2012-03-26  7d 0H 0M 0S
3 2012-04-09 2012-03-26 14d 0H 0M 0S
4 2012-03-26 2012-04-02 -7d 0H 0M 0S
5 2012-04-02 2012-04-02           0S
6 2012-04-09 2012-04-02  7d 0H 0M 0S
```

Comment: OK, can this be used if the numbers are actually dates?

Comment: yes, you can subtract dates from each other.  see `lubridate`

Comment: I added one approach with dates.  But do you really want a square matrix? It seems like you just want differences between all pairs of dates..

Comment: I added to the example to show you. it may not necessarily be square

Comment: My advice is to stop using matrices and switch to using data.frames -- unless there is some reason why you need to use matrices?

Comment: I don't have to use matrices, however, I want it to be a matrix end product as I need to perform matrix calculations on them later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57428/discussion-between-andrewmacdonald-and-shecode).

Answer (score 4):

If your matrix is square, you can use something like this:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 7, ncol = 7)                                               
m <- col(m) - row(m)                                                             
m[lower.tri(m)] <- NA                                                            

> m 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]   NA    0    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]   NA   NA    0    1    2    3    4
[4,]   NA   NA   NA    0    1    2    3
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    1    2
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    1
[7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0
```

Comment: OK, can this be used if the numbers are actually dates?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
a <- matrix(nrows=7, ncols=7)
for (i in 1:7) {
   for (j in 1:7) {
        if (i>j) {
            a[i, j] <- NA
        } else  {
            a[i, j] <- j - i
        }
   }
}
```

I don't know if there's a way to do this without two for loops.